# How can i resolve "NSAlert is being used from a background thread, which is not safe."

Tags: xcode, multithreading, macos

I am using NSalert to display pop-ups. And the data that is to be displayed is sent to alert dynamically from background thread.Some times i found the popup empty in white colour.And i found log NSAlert is being used from a background thread, which is not safe.So what is the safest way to run NSalert

Comment: show alert from main queue

Comment: I am using runmodal to show my alert. then should i run it by using PerformSelectoronMainthread. Then how can i return a value from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use this block around your alert code

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){ ... });`

or a when you display it.

```
self performSelectorOnMainThread
```

Comment: Thank you @Zil Can i get a return value from the method runned in performSelectorOnMainThread. As i am using runmodal to get alerts, i require return value of my call

Comment: I don't know what "runmodal" is, i'm sorry...
Do you need to know what button the user pressed?? (like OK, cancel, or any other button)

Comment: But if i'm guessing i'd say that you could call another function with the selector, that handles the alert maybe with parameters, and from there you could send a "return" (what do you return from an alert anyway??) or a call to another function that does what you need